# Importing repo from gitlab.com to local gitlab instance

Tags: gitlab

I've created a user on gitLab.com and created a new (currently empty) project.

I then downloaded the community edition and installed onto my local machine. I can happily navigate to http://localhost/dashboard/projects and would like to 'import' the project I created on the gitlab.com

I've followed the instructions on my local server for http://localhost/help/integration/gitlab but something is clearly not working out as I never get an option to 'login via gitlab.com' after I have restarted the gitlab app locally.

Here are some details of the setup

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
   {
     "name" => "GitLab.com Oath _ to local",
     "app_id" => "from the app ID on GitLab.com",
     "app_secret" => "from the app secret on GitLab.com",
     "args" => { "scope" => "api" }
   }
 ]
```

The app settings on the server are as follows.

```
Name : GitLab.com Oath _ to local
appId : crazyLongNumberID
appSecret : crazyLongSecretNumber

    Callback URL :
    http://localhost/import/gitlab/callback
    http://localhost/users/auth/gitlab/callback
```

Is there anyone who could give me a gentle shove in the right direction to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't like answering my own questions, but...

so I was being a tad dopey.

the trick was to use git to create a clone of the projet that I had created on my local gitlab instance. Note that this has to be done with the http not ssh version for the project.

`git clone http://localhost/davem/projectName.git`

This creates a sub folder of `projectName` in the directory where i ran the git command.
Then add some files (such as a readme) and then commit this back to the local instance with git push

`git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin master`

Then to link things over to the main gitlab.com site (assuming that you have called the project the same thing.

`git remote add gitlab.com git@gitlab.com:YourUserName/projectName.git`

this adds in the remote project and also gives the server an 'alias' of 'git@gitlab.com' so now we can push to this server with:

`git push gitlab.com`

If I have correctly understood, you can have multiple named servers to push to. eg if you have a colleague who has their own gitLab.com site you can add them as well to with something such as...

`git remote add FriendsName git@gitlab.com:FriendsName/projectName.git`

and now you can push to them with just

`git push FriendsName`

I clearly haven't tested this yet... but I'm guessing this is how it should work. To see the aliases that you have set up use

`git remote -v`

I'm now a happy bunny rabit, and ready to set up some more stuff elsewhere. If I'd made any bad assumptions in here, please feel free to edit accordingly.

David